# Attaching remote files to email in C#

Tags: c#, smtp

I have a web application that uses remote server to upload files to.
I would like to take files from that upload folder and attach them to an email that is being sent by the application from time to time (user triggered action).

Here's the code I wrote in the Controller:

```
var filePath= string.Format("{0}{1}.pptx", System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Files_Storage_Path"], pageId);
string requestorEmail = /* some query that takes email address from DB*/
            Attachment attached_pptx = new Attachment(filePath);
            myController.doMailWithAttachment(requestorEmail, "Some Title", "Some Body", attached_pptx);
```

While testing this on local machine (using local folder paths), everything works great. But when using the server environment, I get an 403 error after triggering the action from the UI.
The credentials and access permissions are well configured from the server to the remote storage server (uploading works great).

Please assist,
Thanks

Comment: Also when server's local path is specified, writing files works fine but reading fails.

Comment: what is the exact exception you get? provide the exception message, inner exception (if any) and stacktrace?

Comment: I get the following error in the logger: eMail sending failed, exception was thrown: Object reference not set to an instance of an object./br The following email address failed: /* email address*/. This error is thrown from the emailing function. However, after logging the name propery of the attachment (inside the emailing function) it looks good.

Comment: Fixed that issue, apparently that I wasn't supposed to read the Configuration file data inside a thread - this caused an exception.